# Redis low CPU usage normal?

Tags: azure, redis

My Redis Cache service instance on Azure is always reporting low CPU usage (never seen it above 25%). Is that normal? is there something I could be doing in order to unload my main server?

note: yesterday during 1 hour span (from 11am to 12am) I logged 1.4 million cache hits

Comment: What do you mean by 'unload my main server'? Also, 1.4 million hits for Redis during one hour is nothing. Things usually go downhill if key size goes up, over 50-100KB. Relax and enjoy the traffic.

Comment: @evilSnobu what if my keys are around 300kb?!?

Comment: Then you'll see milliseconds instead of nanoseconds when getting them under load. It's still a far better approach than reading from disk. May I ask what kind of data is key value and 300 KB in size?

Comment: @evilSnobu sorry, do you mean the key is 50-100KB long or the data the key holds is? in my case, the data is that long, and consist of a elaborated version of a "todo list" and other hard to build or very frequently used data

Comment: Yes, value over hundreds of kilobytes. Again, you don't have a problem, why are you looking for one? :)

Comment: @evilSnobu i only want to know if there's something i can do to better utilize the resource =|
my non-tech manager keeps looking at it and saying that if we don't start using it (despite memory being around 1gb out of 2gb)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network performance of the cache will decrease with memory size (i.e. C0 will not be able to handle as many hits as C2).

You could try to scale down, however i would advise against going to Basic tier since that's Master node only not Master/Slave and you'll start over with a new empty cache if the compute node fails. You will have to start over anyway since you can't go Standard->Basic without creating a new cache.

There's also no SLA in Basic: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/cache/

What's the expiration tag on your keys? If it's short and you're still seeing 1GB of memory being used, your cache size is spot on.